# When I click on "Create An Account" nothing is happening. In the debug console viewpostime pointer on tapping

Tags: firebase, flutter

I created a login and register app using flutter which displays two buttons (login or register),
on clicking register nothing happens. Debug console also shows viewpostime pointers 0 or1.     I am beginner in android development, any help will be appreciated. thanks.

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';


    class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new _LoginPageState();
    }

    enum FormType {
    login,
    register
    }

    class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
    final formKey = new GlobalKey<FormState>();
    String _email;
    String _password;
    FormType _formType = FormType.login;

    bool validateAndSave() {
    final form = formKey.currentState;
    if (form.validate()){
     form.save();
     return true;
    } return false;

    }

    void validateAndSubmit() async {
    if (validateAndSave()){
      try{
        if (_formType == FormType.login){
        AuthResult user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: _email, 
        password: _password);
        print('Signed in : ${user.user.uid}');} 
        else{
          AuthResult user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: _email,  
          password: _password);
          print('Registered User: ${user.user.uid}');
        }
       } catch (e){ print('Error: $e');}
      }
     }

    void moveToRegister () {
    formKey.currentState.reset();
    setState(() {
    _formType = FormType.register;
    });
    }

    void moveToLogin(){
      setState(() {
    _formType = FormType.login;
     });
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text('Flutter login demo'),
        ),
        body: new Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            child: Form(
                key: formKey,
                child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                    children: buildInputs() + buildSubmitButtons() ))));
     } 

    List<Widget> buildInputs(){
    return [
       new TextFormField(
                      decoration: new InputDecoration(labelText: 'Email'),
                      validator: (value) => value.isEmpty ? 'Email can\'t be empty' : null,
                      onSaved: (value) => _email=value),
       new TextFormField(
                    decoration: new InputDecoration(labelText: 'Password'),
                    obscureText: true,
                    validator: (value) => value.isEmpty ? 'Password can\'t be empty' : null,
                     onSaved: (value) => _password=value,
                  ),

     ];
     }

     List<Widget> buildSubmitButtons(){
     if (_formType == FormType.login){
     return [
      new RaisedButton(
                    child:
                        new Text('Login', style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0)),
                    onPressed: validateAndSave,),

      new FlatButton(
                    child: new Text('Create an Account', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0)),
                    onPressed: moveToRegister,
                  )];

    }else{
      return [
      new RaisedButton(
                    child:
                        new Text('Create an Account', style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0)),
                    onPressed: validateAndSave,),

      new FlatButton(
                    child: new Text('Have an Account? Login', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0)),
                    onPressed: moveToLogin,
                  )

      ];
     }

      }}
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Comment: Can you fix to the code so it will be readable? What do you mean by nothing happens? Does it not execute the function in which you have passed to onPressed?

Comment: I have tested your code in dartpad and it is working fine. There might be some other issue. Please provide more information.

Comment: By "nothing is working" I mean that the ui is working tottaly fine but I have linked my app with firebase. When I tap create account my id should be registered which doesnt happen. Firebase dont store any id. Console shows Viewpostime pointer 0